# Trouble figuring out why I'm getting a 404 on my Web API Core localhost endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've seen a lot of similar questions but haven't been able to figure out why I'm getting a 404 when trying to access an endpoint in my web api.

In IIS I have my site setup like this:

[image]

The financial-api app pool is using 'No Managed Code' for .NET CLR Version and NetworkService for Identity.

My controller and endpoint look like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PaycheckTypeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SqlPaycheckDatabaseContext _context;

    public PaycheckTypeController(SqlPaycheckDatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("paycheck-type/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<PaycheckTypeEntity>> GetPaycheckTypeEntity(int id)
    {
        var paycheckTypeEntity = await _context.PaycheckTypes.FindAsync(id);

        if (paycheckTypeEntity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return paycheckTypeEntity;
    }
```

}

Based on the virtual path of `/api/financial`, the controller route of `api/[controller]` and the endpoint route of `paycheck-type/{id}` I would expect `http://localhost/api/financial/api/paycheck-type/4` not to return a 404. Is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reach your action you will have to use url:

```
http://localhost/api/financial/api/paychecktype/paycheck-type/4
```

you can change route to this

```
[Route("~/paycheck-type/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PaycheckTypeEntity>> GetPaycheckTypeEntity(int id)
```

then you can use more simple url:

```
http://localhost/api/financial/paycheck-type/4
```